# Excel Pivot - more than one value a column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an excell pivot table with columns "Ïndustry" and "Country".
The problem is that there are more than one country for each industry, what should I do so that when I chose a country I see all industries linked to the country?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you dragged both the  industry and the country to the rows only or to the columns only. Dragging one of them to the rows and the other to the country will resolve this.

[image]